# CSS min-height doesn't work: It takes the height from width instead..?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, swiper.js

I have set minimum height to be 245px, but somehow it's not applied. I'm making a Slider using Swiper.js anyway

```
<div class="w-[300px] min-h-[245px] flex-shrink-0"></div>
```

You can go to this URL to look at it: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-glade-ltcdrl?file=/src/App.vue

[image]

Notice on the image, the height is 300px instead of 245px when the element next to it is shorter than the image.

The goal is, I want to have the image's height to be 245px when the element next to it is shorter. That's why I put `min-height` there. The image's height will follow the second element's height if the second element's height is taller than the image.

I'm using Vue 3 and Tailwind here, but the "Vue stuff" doesn't matter. It probably matters if you know Vue and you can leverage style or class binding. I'm not sure

I already provided the codesandbox. hope anyone can (fork and) solve the codesandbox once and for all and share it here

Comment: Because min-height sets the MINIMUN height of an element, so your div is greater than 245px, probably your element is bigger then 245px. [min-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height).

Comment: the goal is I want to have the image's height to be 245px when the element next to it is shorter that's why I put min-height there. the image's height will follow the second element's height if the second element's height is taller than the image

Comment: So please modify your question with this details and an example of what is your expected result

Comment: there should be no need to wrap your image in a div in your case if it's the only element in it. Set the height of the wrapping container maybe? Please share your whole HTML structure. This looks like a generic HTML/CSS problem where you might need to restructure something.

Comment: @cloned you can go to the codesandbox on the post, you can fork it and solve it once and for all